# Passing variable-length parameters to formatted string with variable number of placeholders

Tags: python, format, string-formatting

Let's say I have a string as follows:

```
strng = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {}'
tel = '1234'
per = 'Jhon'
```

So as per string formatting, I can use:

```
strng_frmt = strng.format(tel,per)
```

Now let's assume we can have multiple placeholders like below:

```
strng_multiple = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {} Address {} '
```

But only two variables are available as follows:

```
tel = '1234'
per = 'Jhon'
```

And no address variable is available.

So if I do a string formatting like below:

```
strng_frmt = strng_multiple.format(tel,per)
```

I get the error `Tuple index out of Range` or in similar line.

Is there a quick way to fix this problem so that I get an output like below?

```
strng_f = 'Telephone 1234 Contact Person Jhon Address {}'
```

Any clue would be appreciated.

EDIT: As suggested, I am just modifying the question.

In reality, I do not have any prior knowledge of either Number of Parameters or Number of Placeholder. Also values are provided in list.

So I can have following scenarios:

```
Scenario 1: 
strng = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {}' 
vals = [Tel,Per]

Scenario 2: 
strng = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {} Address {}'
vals = [Tel, Per, Add]

Scenario 3:
strng = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {} Address {}'
vals = [Tel,Per]

Scenario 4: 
strng = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {}'
vals = [Tel,Per,Add]
```

So I am using the following method:

```
strng.format(*vals)
```

How can we handle Scenario 3 and 4?

Comment: What is the use case for this? Why does the format string have 3 placeholders if you're only passing two variables to it?

Comment: There's probably a better way to solve the problem. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: just replace `{}` with  `{{}}`. Your code will look like this `strng_multiple = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {} Address {{}} '`

Comment: Shouldn't `strng` be static? Is that also going to be dynamic?

Comment: `strng` is static anyway. But I am showing 4 different scenarios. Scenario 1 and 2 are taken care of.

Comment: @pythondumb See if the new update in my answer section addresses your updated question

Comment: You know you can just directly pass the variables: `f'Telephone Number {tel} Contact Person {pers} Address {addr}'` , right? You no longer need `strng.format(tel,per)`

Comment: Sounds like you want a format-string or methd that inserts defaults for missing variables. Conversely, you could get the same effect by assigning or passing `address = ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
strng_multiple = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {} Address {} '

tel = '1234'
per = 'Jhon'
place_holder = "{}"
strng_frmt = strng_multiple.format(tel,per,place_holder)   

address = "123 sample st"

print(strng_frmt.format(address))
>>> Telephone Number 1234 Contact Person Jhon Address 123 sample st
```

Comment: OP does not want to give an additional parameter. There are ways to solve it without the additional variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in `'{}'` for the unknown variable

```
strng_frmt = strng_multiple.format(tel,per,'{}')
# strng_frmt == 'Telephone 1234 Contact Person Jhon Address {}'
```

This only works if you know there is a third value that you don't have though

Comment: No. It is not true.

Comment: @JoeFerndz how so?

Comment: You dont need to give a third variable. If `{}` is a string that needs to be printed, python format allows you to add those by doubling up those curly brackets. Try `{{}}` and you will see that it prints without the additional 3rd variable or parameter

Answer (score 0):

## Answer 1: solve for printing {}

To print an additional curly brackets, just add a curly bracket.

Here's an example.

```
strng_multiple = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {} Address {{}} '
strng_frmt = strng_multiple.format(tel,per)
print (strng_frmt)
```

The output will be:

```
Telephone Number 1234 Contact Person Jhon Address {}
```

## Answer 2: solve when there are more parameters

Let's assume you send 3 parameters and you have only two to receive, then the third one is ignored.

```
Tel = '1234'
Per = 'Jhon'
Add = 'XYX'
strng_multiple = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {} Address {{}} '
strng_frmt = strng_multiple.format(tel,per,Add)
print (strng_frmt)
```

The output of this will be:

```
Telephone Number 1234 Contact Person Jhon Address {}
```

## Answer 3: solve when there are fewer or more parameters (# of parameters is dynamic)

```
Tel = '1234'
Per = 'Jhon'
Add = 'XYX'
Junk = 'Nothing'

strng_multiple = 'Telephone Number {} Contact Person {} Address {} '

print ('\nScenario 0: vals = []')
vals = []
if len(vals) < 3: vals += ['{}'] * (3-len(vals))
strng_frmt = strng_multiple.format(*vals)
print (strng_frmt)

print ('\nScenario 1: vals = [Tel]')
vals = [Tel]
if len(vals) < 3: vals += ['{}'] * (3-len(vals))
strng_frmt = strng_multiple.format(*vals)
print (strng_frmt)

print ('\nScenario 2: vals = [Tel,Per]')
vals = [Tel,Per]
if len(vals) < 3: vals += ['{}'] * (3-len(vals))
strng_frmt = strng_multiple.format(*vals)
print (strng_frmt)

print ('\nScenario 3: vals = [Tel,Per,Add]')
vals = [Tel,Per,Add]
if len(vals) < 3: vals += ['{}'] * (3-len(vals))
strng_frmt = strng_multiple.format(*vals)
print (strng_frmt)

print ('\nScenario 4: vals = [Tel,Per,Add,Junk]')
vals = [Tel,Per,Add,Junk]
if len(vals) < 3: vals += ['{}'] * (3-len(vals))
strng_frmt = strng_multiple.format(*vals)
print (strng_frmt)
```

The output of this will be:

```
Scenario 0: vals = []
Telephone Number {} Contact Person {} Address {} 

Scenario 1: vals = [Tel]
Telephone Number 1234 Contact Person {} Address {} 

Scenario 2: vals = [Tel,Per]
Telephone Number 1234 Contact Person Jhon Address {} 

Scenario 3: vals = [Tel,Per,Add]
Telephone Number 1234 Contact Person Jhon Address XYX 

Scenario 4: vals = [Tel,Per,Add,Junk]
Telephone Number 1234 Contact Person Jhon Address XYX
```

Comment: What if I have three parameters are passed but only two curl brackets? Like `Telephone Number {} Contact Person {}` But variables passed as `Tel = '1234' Per = 'Jhon' Add = 'XYX'`

Comment: The third parameter is ignored

Comment: If you want the third one to be optional, then you need to pass `{}` as a value and also replace the `string_multiple` format to have the third `{}` instead of `{{}}`

Comment: Ok. If I use as like `strng_multiple.format(*[Tel,Per,Add])` how do you think this would work? The reason I am asking is I don't have any prior clue on number of parameters or number of placeholders.

Comment: In the question section, can you please provide the multiple usecases so a common answer can be presented. I think it is a simple answer. Looks like you want to print a bracket if data does not exist and a value if data exists. Just clarify it in the question section and I can provide you the right answer in my answer section